# Verify Tornado arguments

Tags: python, tornado

I have a server which can accept 0, 1 or many of the following url arguments:

```
/api/cases?id={id}&name={name}&owner={owner}&status={status}
```

So these, amongst other, are correct:

```
/api/cases?owner=me
/api/cases
/api/cases?name=bob&status=waiting
```

Currently, my code looks like this

```
routes = [(r'/cases?([^/]+)', MyHandler)]
tornado.web.Application.__init__(self, routes, settings={})

class MyHandler(APIHandler):
    ACCEPTED_URL_ARGS = ["id", "name", "owner", "status"]

    def get(self, i):
        for key in self.request.arguments:
             if key not in self.ACCEPTED_URL_ARGS:
                   # error
```

Is there a better way to check for the url arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is correct. In Tornado there is no other way to verify that you only got the arguments that you expect than to iterate over `self.request.arguments`.

Answer (score 1):

As Ben says, this is the correct way to do it in Tornado. That being said, the better place for your test would be the `prepare` method; also, a strictly more "pythonic" approach would be to use sets:

```
class MyHandler(APIHandler):
    ACCEPTED_URL_ARGS = {"id", "name", "owner", "status"}

    def prepare(self):
        unwanted_args = self.ACCEPTED_URL_ARGS - set(self.request.arguments)
        if unwanted_args:
            # error
```